# Why doesn't this reopen review have a "Revision" tab?

Tags: bug, review, revisions-list

https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/223325

I see:

> [image]

The question has been edited at least once after closing, so shouldn't there be a tab that shows the changes made, like so:

> [image]

Comment: I don't know if it matters but only the title was edited...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only edits to the *body* of the question will trigger a reopen review. Edits that only change the title and/or tags do not, and are not considered when determining whether to create a revision tab there. As far as the system is concerned, the reopen review exists solely because someone cast a reopen vote on the question.

Comment: Let me pick a wrong place to comment. You should have removed the notice before locking the post.